# Adding time stamp to file name when saveAs not being added

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to saveAs and add a time stamp to the file name but the time stamp is not being added

The file does saveAs but with the original file name so it keeps overwriting the previous file

Thanks

```
Sub Save_Workbook_BackUp()
 Dim sDateTime As String, sFileName As String, s As String

 With ThisWorkbook
   sDateTime = " (" & Format(Now, "yyyy-mm-dd hhmm") & ").xlsm"
   sFileName = Replace(.Name, ".xlsm", sDateTime)
   .SaveCopyAs .Path & "\zMiscellany\BackUps\" & sFileName
 End With
```

Comment: Have you checked if .name includes .xlsm?

Comment: temporarily replace `.SaveCopyAs` with `MsgBox` and then run the procedure.  It will pop up the file name that it's using to save the file.  Is it what you expect it to be?  If not, what is it, and what should it be?

Comment: I tested your code. It works perfectly, creating a different file once the minute has changed and over-writing only when the name has not changed. Consider the possibility that the error you observe is caused by your testing method. Is it possible that you are not aware of ThisWorkbook's path and the copy is created somewhere unexpected?

Comment: No, I can see the file overwriting the old file

Comment: So, what is your workbook called ?